# NS2 maximum connection in cbrgen

Tags: ns2

for this command: ns cbrgen.tcl [-type cbr|tcp] [-nn nodes] [-seed seed] [-mc connections]
[-rate rate].

MC is the maximum connection , pleases can anyone tell me exactly what is it? , is it max connection per node or for the whole simulation ?
what is the suitable value that  can be chosen for 200 node ? thank you in advance.

if anyone know any detailed information please provide me with any available information or links.

Comment: hello friend , 
when i chose that max connection is 30:  dose that mean within the simulation time that i chose there will be 30 number of communication between those nodes.  ?


or it means there each node can have 30 number of simultaneous transmissions ???

thank you

Answer (score 0):

hi for 200 nodes is the value of nn (number od nodes) for (mc : is max connection) to understand let take a look on the cbrgen.tcl file you will find this code

```
   if { $cbr_cnt == $opt(mc) } {
    break
   }
```

before this line there is a loop which is generating connexions and for every generated connexion the cbr_cnt is incremented so when the number of the generated connexion in all the simulation reaches MC maximum connexion the loop breaks

for more understanding try to get a look at the cbrgen.tcl file.